# VREF pin of STM32F303

Tags: stm32, reference

I am designing a custom-made board with STM32F303 MCU and some ADC chips. I have a question regarding VREF pin of the microcontroller. As far as I understood, its main function is to provide a reference voltage for internal ADCs. However, I would like to use a separate external IC voltage reference for improved precision. So can I simply mark it as Not Connected? I've also seen from the datasheet that it is connected to VDDA pin. Will it somehow affect the performance of the MCU if I just leave VREF unconnected? If yes, what should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

VREF is the reference pin for ADC.

It cannot be left unconnected.

If you want to use an external reference then you connect it to VREF pin.

Unless the reference voltage or it's properties are unsuitable for the MCU.

You need to read MCU and reference chip data sheet if they are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

When concerned about pins, your best friend is the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303re.pdf).

There you will find a lot information about the VREF pin. Namely:

- The VREF+ functionality is not available on the 64-pin package. In this package, the VREF+ is internally connected to VDDA.
- VREF+–VDDA(2): Allowed voltage difference for VREF+ > VDDA: max. 0.4 V
- VREF+ must be always lower or equal than VDDA (VREF+ ≤VDDA). If unused then it must be connected to VDDA.
- The current drawn by the internal ADC can vary and is up to 235 µA
- VREF+ Positive reference voltage: min. 2 V - max. VDDA V
- The power supply scheme also suggests, that you should use 1 µF + 10 nF ceramic decoupling capacitors on VREF+